# Octobercms - render fields from repeater groups on theme settings

Tags: field, repeater, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I try to use repeater groups on my theme settings yaml file. So i add the above code to my theme/config/fields.yaml:

```
fields:
    cont:
        tab: Content
        name: cont
        label: Content
        type: text
    content:
        tab: Content
        label: Content
        prompt: Add content block
        span: full
        type: repeater

        groups:
            textarea:
                name: Textarea
                description: Basic text field
                icon: icon-file-text-o
                fields:
                    text_area:
                        label: Text Content
                        type: textarea
                        size: large
            quote:
                name: Quote
                description: Quote item
                icon: icon-quote-right
                fields:
                    quote_position:
                        span: auto
                        label: Quote Position
                        type: radio
                        options:
                            left: Left
                            center: Center
                            right: Right
                    quote_content:
                        span: auto
                        label: Details
                        type: textarea
```

Everything is working fine on theme settings backend and i can insert data on my fields.

Now i try to render those fields on my cms page but no mater what i try i never succeed. I try:

```
{% for fields in this.theme.content%}
     {{ fields.textarea }}
{% endfor %}
```

also

```
{% for fields in this.theme.contents %}
    {% if fields.groups == "textarea" %}
        {{fields.groups.textarea}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But i can't render fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, it seems some confusion there and some wrong variable names :)

let's fix this.

> **End result would be like this :**

```
{% for field in this.theme.content %}            
    {% if field._group == "textarea" %}
        <h1>{{field.text_area}}</h1>
    {% endif %}
    {% if field._group == "quote" %}
        <h1>{{field.quote_position}}</h1>
        <h1>{{field.quote_content}}</h1>
    {% endif %}     
{% endfor %}
```

> what are the mistakes **[ If you are in hurry skip this :) ]** (its here for your improvement it does not server any other purpose **:)** )

You are using `content`so you need to make sure you use correct variable name here you can use `this.theme.content` **not the** this.theme.**>>contents<<**

**next** its `field._group` **not the** `fields.groups`

**and finally** `fields` its

```
fields:
  text_area:
  ....
```

so you need to use them `field.text_area` **not the** `field.textarea` and `field.quote_content` so on ...

if you find any difficulties please comment.

Comment: Thank you Hardik Satasiya!! This was my fault, i used wrong variables.

Comment: Excellent answer with excellent efforts and excellent explanation. I had to upvote it.